# java.net.URL.getContent UnknownServiceException: no content-type

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

Please help me to figure out the problem:
We have 2 servers(old and new). And on the old server code works good, but on the new server this code doesn't work:

```
XWPFDocument doc;
try {
    doc = new XWPFDocument((InputStream) this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filePath).getContent());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

From logs:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: no content-type
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContentHandler(URLConnection.java:1241)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:740)
        at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:1081)
```

The File path leads to docx file which is stored inside resources of one the modules of application.
(And of course I've checked the existence of file.)
So the UrlResource is

```
UrlResource:jar:file:/tomcat/webapps/ourApplication/WEB-INF/lib/moduleName.jar!/internalResourseFolderStructure/file.docx
```

About servers:
They have a little bit different Tomcat versions:
old - Tomcat 9.0.19.0
new - Tomcat 9.0.33.0

Maybe you can get me some tips how to debug it?
(I am totally sure that it is something with server(Tomcat settings or something), but I don't know on this step how can debug such)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContent()):

> #### getContent
>
> This method first determines the content type of the object by calling the `getContentType` method. If this is the first time that the application has seen that specific content type, a content handler for that content type is created.

As it's a file URL there are no HTTP headers, which is why the specific error is "no content-type". Even if the content type was available, Java by default has no idea how to turn a `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` into a Java object.

Perhaps on the old server Tomcat was set up with a MIME mapping for .docx and a `ContentHandler` registered to return something useful.

If what you actually want is an `InputStream`, then use **[`getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))**, which will always work.

Comment: I've changed to getResourceAsStream and it works. But MIME mapping pointed on the new Tomcat as well. So it's very strange situation - when on one server getContent works and on another not... A little bit worry about it..

Comment: I had something similar happening with Tomcat versions 8.5.47 and 8.5.48+, where the first was working without any problem but the second (and onwards) failed with the no content-type error.

Comment: If the older Tomcat defaulted everything to `application/octet-stream` then that would also explain it.